# Необходимо ли наследовать класс EF6 контекста от интерфейса IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, утечка-памяти

Имеется класс контекста:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext, IMyDBContext
{
   //some code
   public virtual DBSet<MyEntity> Entities {get; set;}

   public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
   {
      //some code
   }   
}
```

следует ли наследовать его от IDisposable и реализовывать в нём метод Dispose? Или же этот механизм уже встроен в родительский класс DBContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете посмотреть в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
public class DbContext : IDisposable, IObjectContextAdapter
```

Да, этот интерфейс уже имплементирован в классе *DbContext*